# How to send null to system.in from console with JAVA SE 7

Tags: java, io

I am trying to write a simple class that takes input from the console then outputs it to a flat file.

Currently I need to type a specific string in order to indicate that input from the console has finished. I am using a BufferedRead object, which returns a NULL when reading an EOF from a non-console stream and would like to do similar, but from the console. Can anyone give me some pointers how to do this.

Is there a simple escape sequance that I need to send/type into System.in from the keyboard?

Code is shown below:

```
package writefilestr;

import java.io.*;

public class WriteFileStr
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Ensure that the we have a command line parameter
        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            System.out.println("UASAGE: java WriteFileStr filename");
        }
        else
        {   
            String[] inputBuffer = new String[100];
            int stCount = 0;

            System.out.println("Input Some Strings:");
            try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
            {
                String st = new String();
                boolean eof = false;

                do
                {
                    if (!(st = in.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("EOF"))
                    {
                        inputBuffer[stCount++] = st;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        eof = true;
                    }

                } while(!eof);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            try(BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[0])))
            {      
                for (int i = 0; i < stCount; i++)
                {
                    wr.write(inputBuffer[i]); 
                    wr.newLine();
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : "+e);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException : "+e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a String called "end" or "null" and use a equals() function comparison to terminate input and move on?

Comment: If you want to end input you type into an app in the terminal, on *nix you use Ctrl-D. On Windows it should be Ctrl-Z but I'm less sure of that.

Comment: Alternatively, you can feed a file with prepared input into your program by using `java … < input.txt` in the console to run it.